# Customize default message djangorestframeworksimple-jwt retrieved when the user/password is incorrect?

Tags: django, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using django 3.0.5 ,djangorestframework 3.11.0 and djangorestframework-simplejwt 4.4.0

I have used drf simple-jwt to authenticate, and all works fine. When the password is incorrect, the response is

```
{"detail":"No active account found with the given credentials"}
```

I need to customize this response. I have checked this message inside a dictionary in the class TokenObtainSerializer

```
   default_error_messages = {
        'no_active_account': _('No active account found with the given credentials')
    }
```

I have tried to override this class with no success.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This can be implemented by creating a custom serializer and view.

serializers.py

```
# Import django packages
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

# Import external packages
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer as SimpleTokenObtainPairSerializer


class TokenObtainPairSerializer(SimpleTokenObtainPairSerializer):
    default_error_messages = {
        'no_active_account': _('CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE HERE')
    }
```

views.py

```
# Import external packages
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView as SimpleTokenObtainPairView

# Import my packages
from gadget.auth.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer


class TokenObtainPairView(SimpleTokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = TokenObtainPairSerializer
```

Finally, update your urls to use your new view.

urls.py

```
# Import external packages
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenRefreshView

# Import my packages
from .views import TokenObtainPairView


urlpatterns = [
    # Token authentication
    path(r'token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path(r'token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```